# :not() Not Functioning Correctly

Tags: css, html, hover

I have a navbar made up of a `ul` and some `li` and `a` elements, as shown below:

```css
/*Fonts*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville);

/*Header*/
.header-wrapper {
    background-color: #696969;
 height: 53px;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}
.header-nav {
 background-color: darkblue;
 top: 0;
 height: 48px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;}
.header-nav-element {
 float: left;}
.header-nav-element-logo {
 height: 48px;}
.header-nav-element-link {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 font-family: "Libre Baskerville", serif;
 transition-duration: 0.3s}
.active {
 background-color: #696969;}
.header-nav-element-link:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: #808080;}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper">
  <ul class="header-nav">
    <li class="header-nav-element noselect"><img src="../img/indexlogo.JPG" alt="" class="header-nav-element-logo"></li>
    <li class="header-nav-element noselect active"><a href="#" class="header-nav-element-link">Home</a></li>
    <li class="header-nav-element noselect"><a href="#" class="header-nav-element-link">Bio</a></li>
    <li class="header-nav-element noselect"><a href="#" class="header-nav-element-link">Stances</a></li>
    <li class="header-nav-element noselect"><a href="#" class="header-nav-element-link">Solutions</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, the active tab is lighting up on hover, even though I have specified not to. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your `:not(.active)` is being applied to the `a` but the `active` class is on its parent, the `li`

You could fix it by doing this -

`.header-nav-element:not(.active):hover .header-nav-element-link`

Or by modifying the HTML by moving the `active` class to the element with the class `header-nav-element-link`.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you, kind ma'am!

Comment: awesome! :) Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

As per [the MDN documentation of `:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

> This selector only applies to one element; you cannot use it to exclude all ancestors.

`.header-nav-element` is ancestor of `.header-nav-element-link`.

Change:

```
.header-nav-element-link:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #808080;}
```

to:

```
.header-nav-element:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #808080;}
```

**Corrected snippet:**

```css
.header-nav {
  background-color: darkblue;
  top: 0;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.header-nav-element {
  float: left;
}
.header-nav-element-logo {
  height: 48px;
}
.header-nav-element-link {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-family: "Libre Baskerville", serif;
  transition-duration: 0.3s
}
.active {
  background-color: #696969;
}
.header-nav-element:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header-nav">
  <li class="header-nav-element noselect"><img src="../img/indexlogo.JPG" alt="" class="header-nav-element-logo"></li>
  <li class="header-nav-element noselect active"><a href="#" class="header-nav-element-link">Home</a></li>
  <li class="header-nav-element noselect"><a href="#" class="header-nav-element-link">Bio</a></li>
  <li class="header-nav-element noselect"><a href="#" class="header-nav-element-link">Stances</a></li>
  <li class="header-nav-element noselect"><a href="#" class="header-nav-element-link">Solutions</a></li>
</ul>
```